# Convert timeseries csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

I want to convert a CSV file of time-series data with
multiple sensors.
This is what the data currently looks like:
[image: current data]

The different sensors are described by numbers and have different numbers of axes. If a new activity is labeled, everything below belongs to this new label. The label is in the same column as the first entry of each sensor.

This is the way I would like the data to be:[image: what I want the csv to look like]

Each sensor axis has its own column and the according label is added in the last column.

So far, I have created a DataObject class to access timestamp, sensortype, sensorvalues, and the belonging parent_label for each row in the CSV.

I thought the most convenient way to solve this would be by using pandas DataFrame but simply using `pd.DataFrame(timestamp, sensortype, sensorvalues, label)`
won't work.

Any ideas/hints? Maybe other ways to solve this problem?
I am fairly new to programming, especially Python, so I have already run out of ideas.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a numpy matrix of the columns you require then convert them to a pandas DataFrame.

Otherwise, you can also try to import the csv using pandas from the start.

Also for the following

```
pd.DataFrame(timestamp, sensortype, sensorvalues, label)
```

try referring to the pd.concat function as well. You would need to convert each array to a DataFrame, put them in a list and then concat them with pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html